# Calling constructor from method inside class

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a reset function for a class and the easiest way to go about it would be to use `removeAll()` on the arraylist and call the constructor. However that does not seem to work either because I have the wrong syntax for it for it I am trying something I can't do.

As of now I have a working method, but I would like to clean it up as it is just repeated code (All expect the `removeAll()` statement) from the constructor which is called `StandardDeck()`.

```
public void reset(){
    cardArray.removeAll(cardArray);
    for(int suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++){
        for(int rank = 0; rank < 13; rank++){
            PlayingCard card = new PlayingCard(suit, rank);
            cardArray.add(card);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to [clear](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear()) an arrayList ?

Comment: `call the constructor`..what are you trying to do?

Comment: He's saying that the constructor and reset methods have repetitious code which he wants to clean up...

Comment: No what this process is essentially doing is creating a new deck with all 52 cards and putting it in `cardArray.` The only reason I have `removeAll()` is to clear the old array before I put new values in it.

Comment: You can try arraylist.clear() or cleate a new stance cardArray=new ArrayList<PlayerCard>()

Comment: If you mean the loop is already present in the constructor, just call reset from the constructor so you don't have two loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well your need, you want this :

```
public class StandardDeck {

    List<PlayingCard> cardArray = new ArrayList<>();

    public StandardDeck() {
       reset();
    }

    public void reset() {
        cardArray.clear();
        for(int suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++){
          for(int rank = 0; rank < 13; rank++){
            PlayingCard card = new PlayingCard(suit, rank);
            cardArray.add(card);
          }
        }
    }
}
```

No need to duplicate the loop. And as I pointed before [clear](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear%28%29) is the standard and optimal solution to clear a list.

Comment: Yup that did it I was thinking the other way around though trying to call a constructor to a method instead of calling a method in a constructor.